# Discrete mathematics, prove this is a tautology using logical identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

```
a) [¬p ∧ (p ∨ q)] → q
b) [(p → q) ∧ (q → r)] → (p → r)
c) [p ∧ (p → q)] → q
d) [(p ∨ q) ∧ (p → r) ∧ (q → r)] → r
```

Could anyone give me a step-by-step using logical identities for this problem (preferably C) thanks!

Comment: https://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/120/Chapter5.pdf

Comment: I see you have erased 3 among 4 of the formulas...

Comment: @JeanMarie this is the one I had the most trouble with, should I put them back?

Comment: I think so. Maybe one of them will be chosen as more informative than others.

Comment: Without knowing what the basic logical identities are, we cannot do this. I would take (c) and (d) as basic, but clearly that's not what you're supposed to do.

Comment: @MarkSaving wdym basic logical identities, just prove they are tautology by simplifying?

Comment: @csharp Yes, but what counts as "simplifying"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me consider c):
$$[p \land (p \to q)]\to q$$
$$[p \land (\neg p \lor q)]\to q$$
$$[(p \land \neg p) \lor(p \land q)]\to q$$
$$[0 \lor(p \land q)]\to q$$
$$(p \land q)\to q$$
$$\neg(p \land q)\lor q$$
$$(\neg p \lor \neg q) \lor q$$
$$\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor q)$$
$$\neg p \lor 1$$
$$1$$

Comment: 1 means T right?

Comment: Yes, I use $1$ for truth and $0$ for false.